# Office 365 - "open in new window" option not available for outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365

I have outlook 2013 (MS Office Pro Plus 2013 to be precise) at work, which allows me to open multiple views of my inbox (right click on inbox and select "Open in new window").  This is great as I have one window in date order, and the other in sender order, and it saves me a lot of time.

However, when I go into the web version (Office 365 | Outlook), this option is not available.  Googling shows indicates OWA versions which have this option, but not the Office 365 | Outlook interface which has a totally different look and feel.  The only right-click options which show up are things like "Move down in list" and "Remove from Favorites" etc.

So I tried a workaround by using the browser duplicate tab button, but this just gives me a google window instead of a second mail window, and I don't want to login a second time every time I want this.

Am I being dumb or is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No ways, sorry. You'll need to use the desktop Outlook client to be able to open a new window the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just want multiple views of your inbox?  While there is no link or button - it is possible to do this.

Simply open a new tab and go to https://outlook.office.com.
In theory, this is what your "duplicate" tab option should have done for you.  Not sure why it didn't load.

You can change the view of this 2nd tab independent of the view of the other one.  If you want to see these side by side, simply "tear" the tab out of the main browser session and tile them side by side.

As long as you do this from the same browser instance it will re-use your authentication token, and you won't' have to login a 2nd time.

FWIW - I just validated this behavior on Chrome for Windows build 54.0.2840.99